# Firefox 301 and 302 redirect errors

Tags: php, wordpress, firefox, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I am building a wordpress site and one of my pages constantly again and again gives me a 301 then a 302 error quickly after. This only occurs in FF as Chrome and IE run the page fine. I can't seem to pin down where this error is coming from. I have commented out most of my PHP functions.

Anyone encountered this problem before. Maybe it's a bug in FF or Wordpress?

The 301 and 302 response is: 
`Reload the page to get source for: http://perceptive.nathan/supportarea/account/index.php?error=2`

[image]

[image]

Comment: 301 and 302 is not error. It is redirect.

Comment: Not sure why it keeps requesting it again and agin but only in FF?

Comment: Search for some errors here /supportarea/account/ . And try to clear cookies.

Comment: Cookies deleted and there doesn't appear to be errors. What I don't get is why Chrome and IE are ok but FF isn't? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site http://perceptive.nathan/supportarea/account/index.php, has a bug - page A redirecting to page B which is redirecting back to A; which creates an infinite cycle. I am not sure though why you are facing this only in FF; it may be that FF is triggering a condition, which brings the site bug to surface. I would say that the site still has a bug.

Additionally, doesn't FF complain after a while that it has detected that the call would never succeed? It usually is able to detect cycles of redirected and breaks off the chain early enough.